# How to find the summation of the following series upto 200 terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How to find the summation of

$S=\frac{1}{3\sqrt{6}}+\frac{1}{5\sqrt{7}}+\frac{1}{7\sqrt{8}}+...+\frac{1}{401\sqrt{205}}$

I am trying to evaluate this summation first by finding the $n^{th}$ term of this series. The $n^{th}$ term of this series is $\frac{1}{(2n+1)\sqrt{n+5}}$. Therefore I can write the following series as $$S=\sum_{n=1}^{200}\frac{1}{(2n+1)\sqrt{n+5}}$$. Now after this step, I am thinking of writing the numerator of this summation as $2(n+5)-(2n+1)$. So, the following summation will become $$S=\frac{1}{9}\sum_{i=1}^{200}\frac{(2n+10)-(2n+1)}{(2n+1)\sqrt{n+5}}$$. Finally after this step, I can write this above summation as $$S=\frac{1}{9}\sum_{n=1}^{200}\frac{2\sqrt{n+5}}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{9}\sum_{n=1}^{200}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+5}}$$.

But after this process I got stucked. I can't proceed further. Please help me out with this summation.

Comment: If you want an exact answer, I would guess that there is unlikely to be any convenient formula, because of all the different square roots, which probably will not simplify "nicely".  If you want a decimal approximation, it is quite easily found with any decent computer algebra system.

Comment: Can't say the [numerical result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B1%2F%28%282n%2B1%29*Sqrt%28n%2B5%29%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C200%7D%5D) looks very promising.